# Meaning of 'Contour' in the sentence

Tags: meaning

What does 'Contour' mean in this sentence?
'Contours of the deal favour a particular private defence company'

Does 'contour' here mean features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Contours" are the lines on maps that show the shape of hills or valleys. In this sense, it means "shape" or "outline", in a metaphorical way.

The "shape" of the deal is the general features of the deal, not the details.

I would understand it to mean that, while you could not point to a particular clause that favoured one company, overall the deal was biased.